# How to make a basic plugin system / modloader?

Tags: java, plugins, loader

So I'm trying to make a plugin system like the "Bukkit" plugin system. See right now on my project I have some classes extending my base class "Plugin" and then I add them to my list. How would I make it so I can make it so it automatically loads jars from a "mods" folder that are extending my "Plugin" class and automatically add them to the arraylist? Thank you VERY much for the help, I'm trying to make a mod loader.

Comment: Use a URLClassLoader, and load the jars at runtime

Comment: How would I use it to load the jar though :/ ? I kinda know how to use it load classes.

Comment: You don't load the JAR, you load classes in the JAR by class.  If you want to read the JAR, you can do this by scanning the JAR file in the normal way.

Comment: Ok so I have my plugins folder now ( the directory) how do I use this to scan the jars in their and if their is a class that extends My Plugin class the nadd it to the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do this, but this is what I have done in the past:

```
    private static final String JAVA_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY = "java.class.path";
    private static final String CUSTOM_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY = "custom.class.path";


public static void addPath(String s) throws Exception {
        File f = new File(s);
        URL u = f.toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Class<URLClassLoader> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
        Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[] { u });

        if (System.getProperties().containsKey(CUSTOM_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(System.getProperty(CUSTOM_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY));
            sb.append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
            sb.append(s);
            System.setProperty(CUSTOM_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY, sb.toString());
        }
        else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(System.getProperty(JAVA_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY));
            sb.append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
            sb.append(s);
            System.setProperty(JAVA_CLASS_PATH_PROPERTY, sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

This adds the path to the jar (the s param) to the system class loaders list of URLS, then appends the path to the jar to the end of the custom class path if it exists, or the java class path otherwise. This should allow any other classes whose class loaders can reach the system class loader to use the newly loaded class.

Comment: Alright let's say I wanted to add a new directory , To get the users name I would do something like so right? I never ever messed with files tbh System.getProperty("user.name");

Comment: Ok so I have my plugins folder now ( the directory) how do I use this to scan the jars in their and if their is a class that extends My Plugin class the nadd it to the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a class from a JAR but using a ClassLoader

```
URL jarUrl = ...;
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarUrl });
Class myClass = Class.forName("myjar.mypackage.MyClass", true, loader);
MyPluginInterface myPlugin = myClass.asSubClass(MyPluginInterface.class).newInstance();
```

The myClass will be a class from the jar.  Most likely you will want a JAR of interfaces you share with the plugin.  By using these interfaces you can deal with instances which implement those interfaces easily. i.e. MyClass should implement MyPluginInterface which is an interface you provide.

Note: using a ClassLoader for each plugin allows you to unload the ClassLoader/JAR and load a new version of it, should it change.

Comment: Ok but the problem with that is, it won't detect jars to automatically add them. See I want it so in my directory folder, any jar in there that has a class that extends my PluginLoader class to be added to my arraylist.

Comment: @user3529775 To detect JARs, you need a DirectoryWatcher, just point it at the directory and it will tell you when a file is added, modified or removed.  Note: when a file is added, you need to give it time to be complete. i.e. you have to wait some time for it to stop being written to.

Comment: Ok but how do I detect that they are extending my class (abv know that haha) but through datawatcher, like I want it so it goes through all the jars in my dir, detects their classes that are extending my plugin class and then add them to my arraylist. How would this be done with datawatcher?

Comment: You use the Directory Watcher to detect the new file.  You can scan the JAR by reading it, and then use ASM or similar tool to read/visit the byte code to determine the parent interfaces of the classes in the JAR, note you class might implement a class/interface which implements your interface.

Comment: @user3529775 you might like to look at how OSGi works as it designed to do this sort of thing.

Comment: feels like it could be alot simpler though :/ I mean i could also use this to detect if it extends, Super.class.isAssignableFrom(Sub.class)
 but i dont get how to get the classes in the jars in the first place